# Pyautogui alwayse change the code position of mouse for click and fk up the code

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm facing an issue with PyAutoGUI. Whenever I use it to set commands for accessing and exporting data from a website, the mouse position always seems to change. Everything works perfectly initially, but after restarting the PC and waiting for maybe 30 minutes or less, when I retry running the code, the mouse has shifted a few millimeters, causing everything to go haywire.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, and if so, how did you overcome it?

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm not sure what to try because I haven't identified the root cause of the problem.

```
    import pyautogui
import time

import webbrowser

url = "site"
webbrowser.open(url)

# UTENTE

larghezza_schermo, altezza_schermo = pyautogui.size()

posizione_centrale_x = larghezza_schermo // 2
posizione_centrale_y = altezza_schermo // 2

spostamento_cm = -2
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)

nuova_posizione_y = posizione_centrale_y - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(posizione_centrale_x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')
time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.typewrite("user")

time.sleep(1)

# PASSOWORD

posizione_centrale_x = larghezza_schermo // 2
posizione_centrale_y = altezza_schermo // 2

spostamento_cm = 2
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(posizione_centrale_x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.typewrite("pass")

time.sleep(1)

# LOGIN

posizione_centrale_x = larghezza_schermo // 2
posizione_centrale_y = altezza_schermo // 2


spostamento_cm = 2.8
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y + spostamento_pixel


pyautogui.moveTo(posizione_centrale_x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)


pyautogui.click(button='left')

# RESEARCH

time.sleep(2)

spostamento_cm = 15
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

#  CM SOTTO RESEARCH

time.sleep(1)

spostamento_cm = 13
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

#  CM A DESTRA RESEARCH

spostamento_cm = 9
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_x = pyautogui.position().x - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(nuova_posizione_x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

# DELETE E INSERIMENTO TESTO 1 DATA

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.press('delete')

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.typewrite("1/01/1900")

# DELETE E INSERIMENTO TESTO 2 DATA

spostamento_cm = 16
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_x = pyautogui.position().x + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(nuova_posizione_x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1)

time.sleep(2)

spostamento_cm = 3.5
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

time.sleep(2)

spostamento_cm = 11
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')

nuova_posizione_x = pyautogui.position().x - spostamento_pixel
pyautogui.moveTo(nuova_posizione_x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.press('delete')

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.typewrite(ieri)


# SELCET OK DATA

spostamento_cm = 10.7
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_x = pyautogui.position().x + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(nuova_posizione_x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

spostamento_cm = 3.2
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

# RICERCA DATA

time.sleep(1)

spostamento_cm = 7.7
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

# SELECT DOWLOAD FILE

time.sleep(1)


spostamento_cm = 19.5
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  

nuova_posizione_x = pyautogui.position().x + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(nuova_posizione_x, pyautogui.position().y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

time.sleep(1)

# SELECT ALL COLMN

spostamento_cm = 5.8
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y - spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')


time.sleep(1)

# EXPORT

spostamento_cm = 26.8
spostamento_pixel = int(spostamento_cm * 37.79)  # Considerando 1 cm ≈ 37.79 pixel

nuova_posizione_y = pyautogui.position().y + spostamento_pixel

pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.position().x, nuova_posizione_y, duration=1)

time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.click(button='left')

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Please share relevant code samples and the error you are facing when running the code. Generic questions are difficult to provide feedback or answer. Please read through the stackoverflow guidelines on asking questions and avoid swear words in a forum like this.

Comment: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues file a bug report

Comment: Yes, I know it's generic, but I don't know why it happens. I made changes 4-5 times this week, then I realized there is a problem. The first time, I thought it was because of the height and width I manually entered, but now it seems to take them directly from the screen dimensions.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).